# Switch core mvc front end to angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a net core 2 mvc application hosted on Azure. Its mid development. Now there is a new plan to replace the frontend from MVC Razor views to Angular 2.

I know there are Angular 2 templates for net core, but my question is what it would take to get the MVC controller to serve the startpage of an angular app once authorization has been handled? I have not been able to found any help on other then how to start a project from the beginning.

Im not asking if angular should be used, i am asking if there is a way to integrate it that is reasonably stable and complex?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about net core 2, but generally, you just have to configure your server to serve always the same page (typically index.html) no matter the route. Then in this page, Angular will load, and handles the routing to the correct section itself for example.

Hope that helps

Comment: This was my first idea but it seems more complicated than that when i read on how to run Angular with .Net Core2

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help more than that, I have no knowledge on net core 2 mvc, sorry :(